# Alertas (messagebox) de ventana secundaria aparecen encima de la ventana principal

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo una duda un tanto complicada de explicar y no tiene sentido subir código ya que es extenso y no sé donde está el error. La consulta es:

Tengo dos ventanas, conectadas entre si. En la segundada ventana tengo alertas en caso de que ocurran ciertos eventos. Desde la ventana con un botón, accedo a la ventana 2 antes mencionada y a todas sus funciones. El problema está que al forzar el error a propósito, el error no se muestra donde debería(ventana2) sino en la ventana1, sumando que ésta se me viene por encima de la ventana 2. ¿Alguien sabrá de que puede tratarse este error?

Espero que con las imágenes se entienda:

[image: Ventana Principal del Programa]

[image: Ventana de Ventas]

[image: Problema en sí]

Comment: Hola, Martín. Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. ¿Podrías, por favor, modificar tu pregunta y añadir al menos el error que te está arrojando? Podría, quizá, ayudar a buscar la solución.

Comment: Hola! No subí error porque en teoría no hay error alguno que me arroje, según creo yo es una mala aplicación de las funciones de tkinter :s

Answer (score 2):

Los `messagebox` como cualquier widget, incluidas las variables como `Stringvar`, deben recibir como argumento en el inicializador el widget padre, de no hacerlo su padre implícito será la instancia de la ventana principal de la app, es decir la instancia de `tkinter.Tk`.

El padre de cada widget determinará dónde se mostrará, en el caso del messagebox, la ventana aparecerá encima de la ventana dónde esté su widget padre.

En el caso de un messagebox debes usar el argumento `parent` y pasar una referencia de la ventana sobre la que quieres que aparezca el mensaje de alerta.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


class Secundaria(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Button(
            self, text="Abrir Message bien instanciado",
            command=self.open_good_message).pack(expand=True)
            
        tk.Button(
            self, text="Abrir Message mal instanciado",
            command=self.open_bad_message).pack(expand=True)


    def open_good_message(self):
        messagebox.showinfo(
            "Test", "Hola aparezco donde debo...", parent=self
            )
        
    def open_bad_message(self):
        messagebox.showinfo(
            "Test", "Hola aparezco donde no se me espera..."
            )


class Principal(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Button(
            self, text="Abrir Ventana Secundaria",
            command=self.open_child).pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    def open_child(self):
        sec = tk.Toplevel(self)
        sec.title("Secundaria")
        sec.geometry("650x400+450+350")
        Secundaria(sec).pack(fill="both", expand=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Principal")
    root.geometry("650x400+400+300")
    Principal(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchisimas muchisimas  gracias!!!!!!!!!! Era algo tan simple como eso, aún soy novato y tengo errores así, te agradezco mucho!